# Are Doubles Comparable in Swift

Tags: swift3, xcode8-beta2

Swift 3, Xcode 8β2.
I've implemented a class that sorts Comparable data and attempted to test it using Doubles.  Unfortunately, I'm getting the error `"Cannot convert value of type '[Double]' to specified type '[T]'."`.  I've reproduced the error in the sample code below:

```
class foo<T: Comparable> {
    let data: [T]  = [Double]()
}
```

Am I right is assuming that Doubles are Comparable and, if so, how do I eliminate the error above?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property has a generic type, `T`: it can't be declared as holding a concrete type. Just use `[T]` in the declaration, and use `Double` when instantiating the class.

For my example I've also made the property a var so that I could modify it:

```
class Foo<T: Comparable> {
    var data: [T] = [T]()
}

let f = Foo<Double>()
f.data = [42.0, 33.0]
f.data.sort()
print(f.data)
```

Gives

> [33.0, 42.0]

as expected.

Comment: Got it.  The conformance happens at run-time, not compile-time.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan The conformance is known at compile-time, but with the code you posted in your question, [T] is not the same as [Comparable] because T is equal to whatever comparable type was passed into the generic parameter, as explained by appzYourLife in an answer below. So if Int was passed in, then you would be trying to create a variable with type [T] (which is [Int]), and then initialize it with an array of Doubles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code

```
class Foo<T: Comparable> {
    let data: [T]  = [Double]()
}
```

is that you declared `data` as a **generic type** that must be `Comparable`. It means it could contains any value of type `T`. And `T` is defined when the class is used.

```
Foo<String>()
Foo<Double>()
Foo<Bool>()
```

Look at the example above. In the first case `T` is a `String`.  With this information it should be clear that this line cannot compile

```
let data: [T]  = [Double]()
```

because it would be equivalent to writing

```
let data: [String]  = [Double]()
```

that is obviously wrong.

### Solution

As already suggested by *@Eric D*.

```
class Foo<T: Comparable> {
    let data: [T]  = []
}
```

Now data is populated with an empty array of the correct type.

### Examples

So in this case

```
Foo<String>()
```

it is an array of `String`.

In this case

```
Foo<Double>()
```

it is populated with an array of `Double`.

And finally in this case

```
Foo<Bool>()
```

with an array of `Bool`.